# Reading Safari database contents

Tags: javascript, database, http, https, safari

I'm writing data to the Safari database storage, this is written in a http page.

I then try to read it from a https page, the database is there but all of the tables and rows have dissapeared.

Is this expected bahviour as it's changing between secure and insecure connections?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, all html5 webstorages are under same origin policy. So you can get data only if protocol, host and port are the same for both your pages.

Comment: Thanks, resorted to using HTTPS through the whole website instead to overcome this.